# one to many relation in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two table user and address. User has many requests.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id=models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    catcher_fname = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    catcher_lname = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)



class Address (models.Model):
    address_id=models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

When I hit a user table, I want his address also and return as JSON.

user = User.obejcts.get(pk=2)

it's return me only user data not address :(

Comment: `User` has multiple `Address` which one you want. There is no one-to-one relationship in your models.

Comment: sorry There should be User  user = models.ForeignKey(User) Ihave change my typing mistake

Comment: I want all User address when i hit User.obects.get(pk=2)

Comment: One to many   relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

models.py-

```
class User(models.Model):
    catcher_fname = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    catcher_lname = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)



class Address (models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Note - id field is autoincrementing and in-built in django, you don't need to specify it directly.**
Following is a demonstration how should you link your user obj and address obj.

```
>> from .models import User,Address
>> user_obj = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
>> address_obj = Address.objects.get(pk=address_pk)
>> user_obj.address = address_obj
>> user_obj.save()
```

Later you can access the address from the user object as -

```
>> from .models import User
>> user_obj = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
>> user_obj.address_set.all() (will give the data)
```

Comment: How can i use this in restfrmeworkdjango. I want in rest API

Comment: You have not specify it here..you want them in Django Rest Framework..@Sandeep.. Read about serializers and forignkey in django rest framework docs. You will figure it out frm here

Comment: Please help me I didn't find any good tutorial related to this

Comment: Accept this answer and open another question. Both are completely different things. I will write your answer there.

Comment: Accepted may I add anthor question? for this

Comment: yes. How to implement foreignkey in drf with this models

Comment: Ok I will and send you link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109022/create-a-rest-api-in-django-framework-with-relation Please look into this question

Comment: -1 because this answer is totally wrong. First off, `Address` has a FK to `User` so having another FK from `User` to `Address` is pointless. Second, an user may have multiple addresses so `user.address_set.all()` actually returns all addresses of a user.

Comment: @ozgur agree.. Corrected

Comment: @subha.py It is still wrong. `user_obj.address` doesn't return an address. It returns an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @ozgur changed again..look into it

Comment: @ozgur you can check it in your system. I know user.address_set.all() will work. But related_name query also works and it is cleaner for me.