# create a rest api in django-rest-framework with relation

Tags: django-rest-framework

create a rest api in django-rest-framework

I have 2 tables

Fist table: User

```
id   | PK
Name | varchar(255)
```

Second table: address

```
id      | PK
address | varchar(255)
city_id | int
user_id | FK
```

Now when i hit query on User I also want user address in Json format

Like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 98,
    "name": "rijoj@selectsourceintl.com",

    "address": [
      {
        "id": 51,
        "city_id": 5,
        "addrss": "New York",
      },
      {
        "id": 61,
        "city_id": 5,
        "addrss": "California",
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add your code of models and serializers as well.

Comment: Wel I answered, it would be better if you have put up a bounty.. too tired after writing all the stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

models.py-

```
class User(models.Model):
    catcher_fname = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    catcher_lname = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)



class Address (models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='addresses')
```

**Note - id field is autoincrementing and in-built in django, you don't need to specify it directly.**
Following is a demonstration how should you link your user obj and address obj.

```
>> from .models import User,Address
>> user_obj = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
>> address_obj = Address.objects.get(pk=address_pk)
>> user_obj.address = address_obj
>> user_obj.save()
```

Later you can access the address from the user object as -

```
>> from .models import User
>> user_obj = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
>> user_obj.addresses.all() (will give the data)
```

*Now install django-restframework*

**views.py** -

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
from .serializers import UserDetailSerializer


class UserAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
      serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
      lookup_field = 'id'
      queryset = User.objects.all()
```

**serializers.py** -

```
from .models import User,Address
from rest_framework import serializers


class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('id', 'city_id', 'address')

class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
           model = User
           fields = (
              'id',
              'name',
              'address'
           )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from reports.views import UserAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$',UserAPIView.as_view(), name= 'users'),
]
```